# Setting src as a value in hidden field

Tags: html

I am using a input type as a image in which i am getting the path of the image in src.
Now i want to set the **src as a value in the hidden** field. How can it be done

```
 <INPUT TYPE="Image" ID="Left_front_img" NAME="Left_front_img" value=""  src=" ../folder/1176/images/one.GIF" />

  <INPUT TYPE="Hidden" ID="Left_front_img" NAME="Left_front_img" value="src"  />
</td>
</tr>
```

i require the image path so that i can send it through ajax. i am using jquery form plugin in that  value is not geeting passed so i am using a  and want to set the src of img as a value of hidden field and then pass it to ajax so that i can save it.

Comment: Why don't you go for jquery?? you should try that one

Comment: i am using jquery but here i only need to set the src as a value.

Comment: @rss you question is not clear althrough

Comment: i require the image path so that i can send it through ajax. i am using jquery form plugin in that <input type="image"> value is not geeting passed so i am using a <input type="hidden"> and want to set the src of img as a value of hidden field and then pass it to ajax.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Assuming you named the second one `Left_front_img2`, you could do `tmpVal = document.getElementById('Left_front_img').src;` followed by `document.getElementById('Left_front_img2').value = tmpVal;`. Naturally, this is a 'raw' js solution - you could use jQuery syntax to achieve the same.